# Realtek 8188ce stops working after 2minutes

Tags: 12.10, wireless, network-manager, realtek, hp-pavilion

I am using ubuntu 12.10 on an hp dm4-2191us via wubi with the Realtek 8188ce wifi adapter. Everything works very well with the exception of the wifi. I have used wicd and it didn't worked at all so i went back to Network Manager with variable success.

It works for 30 min - 2 min before i have to reconnect to get it to work again. I would really like to use Ubuntu (it is a better platform in my opinion) but no wifi could really be a deal breaker.

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar problems with the same card but seems fine now I have the drivers installed, see here:
[How to compile Realtek 8188CE wireless driver on Ubuntu 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352470/how-to-compile-realtek-8188ce-wireless-driver-on-ubuntu-13-04)