# How to compile Realtek 8188CE wireless driver on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek

I'm on a Toshiba Satellite C660_EL trying to install [the Realtek 8188CE driver](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true).

```
lspci -v
Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
```

However, I can't get the driver from there to compile (I've installed build-essentials already). Running `make` (with or without sudo makes no difference) I get

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build M=/root/rtl_driver modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
  CC [M]  /root/rtl_driver/base.o
In file included from /root/rtl_driver/base.c:39:0:
/root/rtl_driver/pci.h:247:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtl_pci_probe’
make[2]: *** [/root/rtl_driver/base.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/root/rtl_driver] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

There is a relevant PPA here:
https://launchpad.net/~lexical/+archive/hwe-wireless
but there's no 13.04 build.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had this exact same problem a couple weeks ago, so I put a working driver up on my Git Hub.  I also changed it so that it does away with the 20 dBm Tx Power limit and let's you go up to 33 dBm.  [The instructions](https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver/blob/master/README.md) are in [the repo](https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver).

You can clone this with:

```
git clone https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver.git
```

If you don't have Git installed, you may need to install it first:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

If you are curious, the compile issue is a result of a Linux kernel header change with the 3.8.x kernel.  They removed a `#define` that breaks this code.  It doesn't affect functionality though, it just stops it from building.  I've been running my compiled driver for several weeks now and it is *way* better than the one installed by default on 13.04

Comment: I actually just worked out the fix, but your version is nicer than mine, I just deleted all the __devinit's by hand!

Comment: Ha, I don't have enough rep to upvote your answer, sad times

Comment: @daknowles No worries.  I appreciate it :-)

Comment: For future travelers, I have updated the repo for Ubuntu 13.10.  The 13.04 version is still there, but make sure you switch to the `ubuntu-13.04` branch otherwise you'll get compile errors because of the changed Linux headers